# How to use variable from do block assignment line in a where clause?

Tags: haskell, scope, monads, where-clause, do-notation

I have the following sample of code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

main = do
  putStrLn "Please input a number a: "
  a :: Int  <- readLn
  print a

  putStrLn "Please input a number b: "
  b :: Int  <- readLn
  print b

  putStrLn ("a+b+b^2:" ++ (show $ a+b+c))
    where c = b^2
```

For some reason I cannot use variable `b` in a `where` clause, the error I get is the following:

```
Main3.hs:13:15: error: Variable not in scope: b
   |
13 |     where c = b^2
   |               ^
```

Any ideas how to make `b` available in the `where` clause?

Comment: Roughly put, `where` relates to the last `=` symbol (or group of guards), so your code parses as `main = (do ....) where c=b^2`, triggering the error. There is no way to fix it using `where`, since `expression where x=..` is not an expression. We need `let` here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `let` instead of `where`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

main = do
  putStrLn "Please input a number a: "
  a :: Int  <- readLn
  print a

  putStrLn "Please input a number b: "
  b :: Int  <- readLn
  print b

  let c = b^2
  putStrLn ("a+b+b^2:" ++ (show $ a+b+c))
```

The reason for the problem is that variables in the `where` clause are in scope for all of `main`, but `b` isn't in scope until after `b :: Int  <- readLn`. In general, `where` clauses can't reference variables bound inside of a `do` block (or anywhere to the right of the `=`, for that matter: e.g., `f x = y*2 where y = x+1` is fine but `f = \x -> y*2 where y = x+1` is not).